# Pandas is confusing the date format

Tags: python, pandas

Something of context: Using the format YY/mm/dd HH-MM-SS, today is 2022-04-01 15:00:33 (Fake hour)
I'm exporting a pandas DataFrame to CSV in the next line

```
df.to_csv('filepath/archive.csv', header=False, index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', mode='a')
```

But I have as result this:

```
"0.85","0.7","0.5","0.7","0.65","0.65","0.8","0.8","0.7","0.7055555555555555","2022-01-04 15:00:33"
```

Look how the hour confuses the day and the month and I have in my code "Year-Month-Day" and it presents as final result "Year-Day-Month" like this:

```
"0.85","0.7","0.5","0.7","0.65","0.65","0.8","0.8","0.7","0.7055555555555555","2022-04-01 15:00:33"
```

Is this a bug of pandas?
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: The middle row seems to be in the format you wanted it to be. What exactly happens after it, as in what exactly happened before the the bottom row? Which of the rows is what the `df.to_csv` example appends to `filepath/archive.csv`? What does `print(repr(df[10]))` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-04-01 15:00:33", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(dt)
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.85,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.65,0.65,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7055555555555555,dt]])
print(df)
df.to_csv('archive.csv', header=False, index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', mode='a')
```

Output is:

```
2022-04-01 15:00:33
     0    1    2    3     4     5    6    7    8         9                   10
0  0.85  0.7  0.5  0.7  0.65  0.65  0.8  0.8  0.7  0.705556 2022-04-01 15:00:33
```

... and archive.csv contains the following line:

```
0.85,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.65,0.65,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7055555555555555,2022-04-01 15:00:33
```